# Handling Laravel's UserTrait with ApiGen

Tags: php, laravel, apigen

I've started using ApiGen with a Laravel project.

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
The class Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait is in use but has not been found in the defined sources.
```

Clearly it's complaining because Laravel's `UserTrait` isn't defined in the same file, but I obviously don't want to include my `vendor/` directory and from the documentation I don't see how I can handle this. I want to use Jenkins to generate the documentation and because it returns a non-zero exit code it registers as an error, and thus breaks the build.

Here's my `apigen.neon`:

```
source:
    - app 

destination: docs

exclude:
    - "*/tests/*.php"
    - "*/database/*"

tree: true

sourceCode: true

todo: true

autocomplete:
    # default
    - classes
    - constants
    - functions
    # other
    - methods
    - properties
    - classconstants

title: My web app
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2019: <strike>I'm current owner of ApiGen.</strike>**

**ApiGen development stopped 3 years ago and it lacks of support and meaning. I do not recommend to use it**

---

This should be fixed in last version (RC5 at the moment).
See: https://github.com/apigen/apigen/releases

For any further issues you can use [Github issues](https://github.com/apigen/apigen/issues) to report them

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much! I didn't realise this was an issue with ApiGen - I thought I'd misconfigured it, otherwise I would have opened an issue.

Comment: Just update: ApiGen is not maintained since 2017 and I'd say is slowly dying. Better use Github or PHPStorm / IDE as maintained replacement.